# Minimum number of zeroes of $g(x)=(f'(x))^2+f''(x)f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $f(x)$ is a twice differentiable function such that
$f(a)=0,f(b)=2,f(c)=-1,f(d)=2,f(e)=0$
where $a<b<c<d<e,$ then how many minimum number of zeroes does $g(x)=(f'(x))^2+f''(x)f(x)$ have in the interval $[a,e]?$

What way do I attempt a solution??

Comment: Not sure whether this helps or not, but $g(x) = \frac{1}{2}(f(x)^2)''$.

Comment: g(x)=1/2(f(x)^2)'', thanks for the information but how does it help? In the interval [a,e], the function has about 4 zeroes, hence if f is a polynomial, it must be, at least biquadratic. This means g is degree 6, but that does not help us to find number of zeroes in [a,e]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the function $h(x)=f(x)f'(x)$ and use [Rolle's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Rolle) [theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem).

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: @AshishGaurav: Note that $g(x)=h'(x)$. How many zeros does $h$ has? Hint:The function f has at least $4$ zeros and and $3$ relative extremes. Therefore ...

Comment: Got it, thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

$$g(x) = \frac{d}{dx} [f(x) f'(x)]$$

$f(x)$ has a minimum of $4$ zeroes in the given interval, while $f'(x)$ has $3$ in different places (between $a$ and $b$, $b$ and $c$, and $c$ and $d$).  $f(x) f'(x)$ then has a minimum of $7$ zeroes in this interval, and consequently,  its derivative $g(x)$ has $6$ zeroes at a minimum.